# pgfplot ybar remove bar offset

Tags: pgfplots, bar-chart

I have this pgfplot

```
  \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline]
\begin{axis}[
  ymajorgrids,      
  legend style={at={(0.5,1.05)}, anchor=south,legend columns=3},
  ybar,
  bar width=0.5cm,
  ylabel=Ratio vs. original,
  xtick={1, 2, 3, 4},
  ymin=0,
  width=\textwidth,
  height=7cm
  ]
  \addplot+ [DarkRed] (1, 0.9166278045494584);
  \addplot+ [BlueViolet] (2, 0.9745841753458725);
  \addplot+ [CadetBlue] (3, 0.7903000155448467);
  \addplot+ [Blue] (4,0.9375097155293016);      
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Which gives this output
[image]

How can I remove the offset of the bars from the tikcs on the x axises ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess that you looking for the following:

[image]

In MWE below are changes in comparison to your code fragment are marked by `% <---`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz,xcolor}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline]
\begin{axis}[
  ymajorgrids=true,
  %legend style={at={(0.5,1.05)}, anchor=south,legend columns=3}, % it is not used
  ybar=2mm,                     % <----
  bar width=8mm,                % <----
  bar shift=0mm,                % <---- remove offset
  ylabel={Ratio vs. original},
  enlarge x limits=0.2,
  width=0.5\textwidth,          % <----
  height=7cm
  ]
\addplot + [red]      coordinates {(1, 0.9166278045494584)};
\addplot + [green]    coordinates {(2, 0.9745841753458725)};
\addplot+ [magenta]   coordinates {(3, 0.7903000155448467)};
\addplot+ [yellow]    coordinates {(4,0.9375097155293016)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot :) Can you explain why there is a need for coordinates? in the addplot command? Also I was told, but that might be wrong, that with tikz one should you CM as much as possible and not MM was that wrong?

Comment: @LarsNielsen, I'm afraid that I don't understand your comment :-(. Tasks of \addplot` commands are drawing function. with given options (in your cases they are colors), options of  `axis` environment define diagram style (axes, kind of diagram, axes' labels etc. What you mean with CM and MM? When I preparing MWE, I try to wrote really minimal and short code, prefer standard solutions described in packages' manuals etc. Well, in this I don't succeed always :-).

Comment: @Zarko Dear Zarko I remove my bad answer :-)

Comment: @Sebastiano, next time you will write better, a winning one.. I'm confident in this!

Comment: I didn't really understand the question and I have tried. Thank you very much and I hope with all my heart that my reconstruction was useful as I did not have a complete code. The positive vote was for you.

Comment: @Zarko I was told that for instance width should be made with cm and not mm. I guess that is false? Also what I mean with the coordinates. I have seen a lot of examples plotting coordinates, where the coordinates keyword is not used, so was wondering why you use it :) If it is best practice and such :)

Comment: @Sebastiano thanks for your answer as well. Sorry if my question is hard to understand :)

Comment: @LarsNielsen, TikZ default length units are "cm" (centimeter) and "pt" (point), so many times you not need to explicit write units. However use of "mm" is not forbidden. In some professions, as is for example mechanical ans electrical engineering, for lengths are usual used millimeters ... and those people many times use them also in TikZ, when a writing of units is required.